# Ошибка #1064 в SQL запросе

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что тут не так. Пытаюсь виртуальную таблицу.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `Задание в заказе`;
CREATE PROCEDURE `Задание в заказе` 
(IN `@Ид\Заказ` INT
)
BEGIN
SELECT `З`.`Регномер` AS `Регномер (задания)`
,   `С`.`Код` AS `Код (вида задания)`
,   `С`.`Название` AS `Название (вида задания)`
,   `З`.`Содержание` AS `Содержание (задания)`
,   `З`.`Цена` AS `Цена (задания)`
FROM `Задание` `З`
INNER JOIN `Справочник` `С` ON `З`.`Ид\Вид задания` = `С`.`Ид`
WHERE `З`.`Ид\Заказ` = `@Ид\Заказ`
;END
```

В БД есть таблица `Задание` с атрибутами – `Регномер`, `Ид\Заказ`, `Содержание`, `Цена` и таблица `Справочник` с атрибутами – `Ид`, `Код`, `Название`.

Ошибка:

```
#1064 - У вас ошибка в запросе. Изучите документацию по используемой версии MySQL на предмет корректного синтаксиса около '' на строке 14
```

Comment: Вопрос решен. BEGIN и END были лишними.

Comment: На самом деле ошибка имела иную причину - финальное END блока BEGIN-END не было закрыто точкой с запятой. Но, поскольку процедура состоит из одного запроса, обрамляющий блок действительно избыточен.